# construct dict from 3 lists using Ansible

Tags: arrays, json, list, dictionary, ansible

I successfully construct vars of lists like:

```
TASK [get hostname] *****************************************
Sunday 07 March 2021  22:57:44 -0500 (0:00:00.254)       0:00:08.625 ********** 
ok: [ansiblehost] => {
    "varmachine": [
        "machine1", 
        "machine2", 
        "machine3"
    ]
}
TASK [Ostype] ***************
Sunday 07 March 2021  22:57:44 -0500 (0:00:00.065)       0:00:08.691 ********** 
ok: [ansiblehost] => {
    "varosname": [
        "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 (64-bit)", 
        "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 (64-bit)", 
        "windows Server 2016 (64-bit)"
    ]
}
TASK [domaines] **********************************
Sunday 07 March 2021  22:57:44 -0500 (0:00:00.084)       0:00:08.776 ********** 
ok: [ansiblehost] => {
    "domainevar": [
        "example1.com", 
        "example2.com", 
        "example3.com"
    ]
}
```

so now I want to generate a list of dict using previous variable lists:varmachine,varosname and domainevar like following :

```
[{"name":"machine1","OSname":"Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 (64-bit)", "Domaine":example1.com}, {"name":"machine2","OSname":"Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 (64-bit)", "Domaine":example2.com},
"name":"machine3","OSname":"windows Server 2016 (64-bit)", "Domaine":example3.com} ]
```

in other word someting like :

```
[{"name":varmachine[0],"OSname":varosname[0], "Domaine":domainevar[0]}, {"name":varmachine[1],"OSname":varosname[1], "Domaine":domainevar[1]},
"name":varmachine[2],"OSname":varosname[2], "Domaine":domainevar[2]} ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The task below does the job

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        _list: "{{ _list|default([]) + [dict(_keys|zip(item))] }}"
      with_together:
        - "{{ varmachine }}"
        - "{{ varosname }}"
        - "{{ domainevar }}"
      vars:
        _keys: [name, OSname, Domaine]
```

gives

```yaml
  _list:
  - Domaine: example1.com
    OSname: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 (64-bit)
    name: machine1
  - Domaine: example2.com
    OSname: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 (64-bit)
    name: machine2
  - Domaine: example3.com
    OSname: windows Server 2016 (64-bit)
    name: machine3
```